# Sync files from linux server to windows machine

Tags: backup, rsync

I have a linux webserver, running apache and mysql. I want to back up on my windows desktop pc the remote files (/home and /var/lib/mysql) with a total capacity of 34 GB. The point is that i need to do it with a network speed limit, and to be able to continue the backup even if my windows pc was restarted.

After the initial backup, i want the program (i can't find a good one) to sync the files every day and to copy them if there are new files on the linux server. And all that good stuff has to be done in background, with a speed limit.

Could you suggest me what software to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual answers include

- [rsync](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) ([Related Question](https://superuser.com/questions/126884/best-way-to-automatically-synchronize-files-between-linux-and-windows), use [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync) for Windows)
- [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)
- [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction) ([Related Question](https://superuser.com/questions/138636/mirror-backup-from-ssh-sftp-to-windows))

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at our tool, yintersync...it manages rsync and is designed to recover automatically from disconnections, restarts etc.

[Windows Rsync : Yintersync](http://www.yinter.net)